# Interactions with implicit conversion between three types?

Tags: c++

Suppose we added a new class template to the `<string_view>` header of the C++20 standard library:

```
template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>>
class basic_string_view;  // existing

template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>>
class basic_cstring_view;  // new
```

We want to make it so that:

- `std::cstring_view` is implicitly convertible to `std::string_view`
- `std::string` is implicitly convertible to `std::cstring_view`
- `std::string` (to remain) implicitly convertible to `std::string_view`

If we add to the definition of `std::basic_cstring_view`:

```
operator basic_string_view<charT, traits>() const noexcept; // new
```

and we add to the definition of `std::basic_string`:

```
operator basic_string_view<charT, traits>() const noexcept; // existing
operator basic_cstring_view<charT, traits>() const noexcept; // new
```

Is this going to create problems, ambiguities?  Could it break any  existing code that uses `std::string_view` or `std::string`?

I'm concerned that there are now two paths between `std::string` and `std::string_view`.  That being the direct path, and the two step conversion via `std::cstring`.

To clarify the specific question for the "closer":

What is an example of a currently working program that uses `std::string` and/or `std::string_view`, that would, given the described changes to `<string_view>` and `<string>`, stop working?  Or does such an example not exist?

Comment: Only one user conversion is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm concerned that there are now two paths between std::string and std::string_view. That being the direct path, and the two step conversion via std::cstring.

Only one of those paths is valid, because implicit conversion sequences with more than one user-defined conversion are not valid candidates.

To clarify, "user defined" in context of implicit conversions doesn't refer to the distinction from the standard document, but refers to all conversion operators and converting constructors of classes (i.e. user defined data types).

> Or does an example [of a currently working program that uses `std::string` and/or `std::string_view`, that would, given the described changes to `<string_view>` and `<string>`, stop working] not exist?

Such example does not exist.